# How to enable visual feedback of selection in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm making my first UICollectionView. The layout has gone well. I have gantt style bars with labels on them. I've set `allowsSection = YES` on my `UICollectionView`. If I add delegate methods such as:

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"collectionView:shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath: %@", indexPath);
    return YES;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath: %@", indexPath);
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"collectionView:didHighlightItemAtIndexPath: %@", indexPath);
}
```

I see that selection seems to be happening at some level. But there's no visual feedback of the selection. I do have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` subclass, and I add a `CAShapeLayer` to its `contentView`. I specifically avoided messing with the subclass's own layer because of Apple's docs:

> To configure the appearance of your cell, add the views needed to present the data item’s content as subviews to the view in the contentView property. Do not directly add subviews to the cell itself. The cell manages multiple layers of content, of which the content view is only one. In addition to the content view, the cell manages two background views that display the cell in its selected and unselected states.

Which leads me to believe that I'm supposed to get visual selection feedback for free. I made sure that my `CAShapeLayer` does not cover the whole area of the cell's layout. It's a rectangle inset.

So what am I missing?

Comment: When you remove the CAShapedLayer do you get the cell to highlight or no?

Comment: Did you try setting cells selectedBackgroundView property?

Comment: @Ladislav No, I assumed it was automagic. I mean, the documents didn't say I **had** to, so I figured some default existed, and I set that property only if I wanted to *customize* it. Is that not the case? If not... Make your comment an answer so I can give credit.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Feel both like an idiot, but also annoyed that they never point out "we'll make it all work for you BUT not that".

Comment: Yeah, I think that collection views do not behave in the same way as tableviews do, where cell selection is done by OS automatically, and you have to explicitly stop it from showing selected state. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the cell's selectedBackgroundView property.

Comment: I should add as an aside, that after all was said and done, I chose to override `setHighlighted:` and `setSelected:` in my subclass to and use those hooks to use the layer's shadow properties to show a selection ring.